# What is the enthalpy change for the following equation?

Tags: enthalpy

The equation we need it to change to 
\[\ce{FeO + CO ->Fe + CO2}\]

The three equations and delta heat:

\[
\begin{align*}
\ce{3Fe2O3 + CO &-> 2Fe3O4 + CO2} &\Delta H=-47.0\ \mathrm{kJ}\\
\ce{Fe2O3 + 3CO &-> 2Fe + 3CO2} &\Delta H=-25.0\ \mathrm{kJ}\\
\ce{Fe3O4 + CO &-> 3FeO + CO2} &\Delta H= 19.0\ \mathrm{kJ}
\end{align*}
\]

What is the enthalpy change and how to combine the 3 equations to make the above equation? (Please show work)

Thank you,
     Tiffany

Comment: Please show your efforts  into solving the problem. What have you tried that didn't get answers?

Answer (score 1):

> […] how to combine the 3 equations […]

#### **Equations** is the keyword!

This is just an example on how to solve a system of linear equations, disguised as a chemistry problem.

If the calculation with $\ce{FeO}$, $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{Fe}$, $\ce{CO2}$, etc. feels strange, just translate them to $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, etc.

The question for the enthalpy of the first reaction therefore is equivalent to finding the solution for

\[y = x_3 + x_4 - x_1 - x_2 \]

#### How to work in the other equations?

\[\ce{3Fe2O3 + CO -> 2Fe3O4 + CO2} \quad\quad\Delta H=-47.0\ \mathrm{kJ}\]

You have the reactants, the products and the enthalpy: translate that to a mathematical equation following the naming scheme introduced above:
\[2x_6 + x4 - x_2 - 3x_5 = -47.0\]
Do the same for the other two equations, rearrange and try to solve the equation system.